# How to make listeners work in Firebase for multi-location updates while offline

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

This could possibly be a bug in Firebase. The `childAdded` listener does not get triggered if I post to level 2 node and higher ?

This is my schema:

```
root: {
    company1: {
        05062017: {
           user1: { 
                 "1": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" }
                 "2": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" }
                 "3": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" }
                 "4": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

1. The iOS device is offline.
2. I am listening to the following node using `

   ```
   .observe(.childAdded..
   ```

   on

   ```
   root / company1 / 05062017 / user1
   ```
3. Now, lets say I want to add a new object under `employee1`:

   ```
   5: { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" }
   ```
4. If I add the object like this the listener gets triggered:

   ```
   updateChildValues(["root/company1/05062017/user1/5": ["a": "aa", ...]])
   ```
5. The problem is if I want to add an object like this

   ```
   updateChildValues([
       "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/a": "aa",
       "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/b": "bb",
       "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/c": "cc", 
   ])
   ```

   In that case the listener doesn't get triggered until I connect to Internet.
6. If I connect to Internet, then disconnect again, everything works again. The problem is that sometimes in the beginning of the day, the Internet is not available so I have to start working without connection.

I worked around it for now, I would just like to know what is the reason behind this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but part of Firebase's guarantees. It is definitely behavior that not many developers hit though, so I'll try to explain...

The Firebase client only fires an event for a location when it is certain that it has the complete data for that location.

---

This code:

```
updateChildValues(["root/company1/05062017/user1/5": ["a": "aa", ...]])
```

Is the same as:

```
.child("root/company1/05062017/user1/5").setValue(["a": "aa", ...])
```

This replaces all data at `root/company1/05062017/user1/5`, and thus the client can be certain the `["a": "aa", ...]` is the complete new data for the location.

---

But when you run this code:

```
updateChildValues([
  "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/a": "aa",
  "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/b": "bb",
  "root/company1/05062017/user1/5/c": "cc", 
])
```

The client has no guarantee at any point that it knows all data at `root/company1/05062017/user1/5` (since you're not writing that node specifically), so it doesn't fire events until it has reconciled with the server.